# Is there a shared pointer with a single strong owner and multiple weak references?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers

I am looking for a smart pointer similar to `Arc`/`Rc` except that it does not allow shared ownership.

I want to have as many `rc::Weak` references as I need, but I only want **one** strong reference, a.k.a owner. And I want to enforce that with the type system.

`Arc`/`Rc` can be cloned, and they can be owned at several places.

Rolling up my own smart pointer would be an option, but I believe such data structure should already exist, even if outside the standard library.

I am looking for a data structure providing this kind of interface:

```
impl MySmartPointer<T> {
    fn new(object: T) -> Self;
    fn weak_ref(&self) -> WeakRef<T>;
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T;
}

impl WeakRef<T> {
    /// If the strong pointer `MySmartPointer` has been dropped,
    /// return `None`. Else return Some(&T);
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&T>;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)?

Comment: I do not think that RwLock will do the trick. Even though RwLock can be owned in one place, I do not think I can throw around weak references to the value encapsulated by RwLock. What if the original RwLock gets deleted?

Comment: Just for information, what is a usecase for this?

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña RW locks can chose to let more reader enter or more writers. They can have different levels of writers that more or less force readers to wait... The last (or last and only) master_strong owner of a resource could decide to invalidate the weak owners, only letting those who had already upgraded to strong_from_weak, who wouldn't be able to create more owners. It's a "we are closing, only those customers in the line can check out" decision.

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume it exists with types `Strong<T>` and `Weak<T>`.  How do you use `Weak<T>`?  You need some kind of fallible "upgrade" step, so what does `Weak<T>` upgrade to?  It can't be to a plain reference (as you've stated), because `Strong<T>` **needs** to know whether or not any "upgraded" `Weak<T>`s exist.  If it didn't, it could deallocate its storage whilst the value is still being accessed.

So `Weak<T>` must upgrade to some kind of `SemiWeak<T>` which keeps the underlying allocation alive... which is exactly what shared ownership *is*.

What if you somehow guaranteed that `Strong<T>` couldn't be deallocated before all `Weak<T>`s go away?  Congratulations, you've just re-invented `T` and `&T`: you could literally just use those instead.

Alright, so *what if* you made it so that `Weak<T>` upgrades into a `SemiWeak<'a, T>` that is tied to the lifetime of the `Weak<T>` so that it *can't* outlive it, and can only be a temporary?  All you're really doing in that case is *hiding* the fact that you've got shared ownership.  Under the hood, `SemiWeak` would still need to guarantee the underlying `Strong` can't go away.  You could trivially build such a type from `Rc<T>` in perhaps ten minutes.  This would effectively give you a type that is exactly like `Rc<T>`, with the same performance and memory cost, but less useful.

In addition, that `get_mut` method can't exist.  There's no way to prevent `SemiWeak<T>`s from existing.  Unless you use borrowing but, again, that's just using `T` and `&T`.

So, no, I don't think this exists, nor do I believe it *can* in the form you've described.

---

As a final aside, just having `Weak<T>` *at all* is a form of shared ownership, because those `Weak<T>`s *need to point to something*.  In the case of `Rc<T>`, the weak counter is stored right alongside the strong counter, so whilst the value can be destroyed, the allocation *itself* sticks around.  You could split the two, but now you're paying for two allocations *and* double indirection (probably leading to more cache misses).

Comment: IOW, a "weak reference" is a strong reference to meta info.

Comment: You could still have a bunch of strong references and weaker strong references that keep the object alive but that don't keep weak references upgradable. The store is closing, some customers will still be allowed to buy what they have in their cart, other will have to leave... You can prevent some customers from upgrading to close earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but the crate refbox https://docs.rs/refbox/latest/refbox/index.html seems to do exactly that. I don't know how safe it is to use as it's stated to be experimental in the docs. 
I tried implementing it myself but couldn't solve the ownership and created use after free scenarios. I don't know how or if the crate owner solved or ignored these issues.